# How to find your lost Disqus Thread Identifier?

Tags: wordpress, multithreading, identifier, disqus

Confused Disqus thread IDs per post. Had to revert to correct thread IDs. Unable to find the thread identifiers through Disqus Admin Panel.

Comment: *"Check the answer for the solution"* - did you imagine people would do otherwise?

Comment: There are many people who may churn (also it's all about presentation, better readability; there are many people editing the question to solved etc. even it has marked as answered).

But hey; thanks for pointing out my rhetorical mistake. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your Disqus admin panel.
2. Get your Disqus forum shortcode by the url %YOURFORUMNAME%.disqus.com/admin/
3. Go to Disqus API Applications: https://disqus.com/api/applications/
4. Register a new application (Label, Description, Organization, Web-Site; enter host domain of your disqus forum)
5. Go to Disqus API Console: https://disqus.com/api/console/
6. Select listThreads under Forum category from dropdown.
7. Add parameter: "forum" and "%YOURFORUMNAME%", click submit.
8. Copy JSON data.
9. Get it to a readable JSON parser/converter for easier workflow. https://konklone.io/json/
10. Use "id" and "clean_title" column to enter your correct thread ID for wordpress.

Comment: It seems that this now doesn't work directly. You need to `listCategories` first to find the category id, and then use the category id to `listThreads`.